# CFL condition in Stokes equation

Tags: navier-stokes, advection-diffusion, cfl

Does the CFL condition play any role in a pure Stokes flow, i.e. convective term is neglibile, or vanishing? If not, what is the "equivalent" condition for stability? I have read something about the diffusional time scale but it's quite vague. Anyone with in-depth insight?

And a quotation from a paper [1]:
*"The time step is $3.10^-3\dot\gamma^-1$, corresponding to a CFL number based on the diffusional time scale $CFL_d=v\Delta t/\Delta^2$ of 50."*

[1] Gallier, S., Lemaire, E., Lobry, L., & Peters, F. (2014). A fictitious domain approach for the simulation of dense suspensions. Journal of Computational Physics, 256, 367-387.

Comment: Do you mean the time-dependent Stokes equation? It would be useful to state the exact problem you are considering.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I will clarify! I mean in the flow regime that the Navier stokes equations reduce to the Stokes equation:
$\mu\nabla^2\mathbf{u}-\nabla p=0$

Comment: But there is no time dependence here. The CFL condition relates the time step size to the mesh size -- but you don't have a time step here.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Although it is evident that this not apply in the steady case, does it apply in the unsteady case? $$\mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}- \nabla p = \frac{\partial \rho \mathbf{u}} {\partial{t}}$$ Generally we would solve the diffusion operator with an implicit scheme, so I don't think you would get a CFL in this condition no?

Comment: In the time dependent case, if you use an implicit time stepping scheme, then the CFL stability condition does not apply. If you use an explicit time stepping scheme, then a variation of the condition applies indeed.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Sorry for the confusion, I was referring to the unsteady case of course, I just looked up the equation from the analytical textbook which simplified it to the steady equation!
So, isn't that the CFL is mainly used for the convective parts, so we need a new "CFL" number on the viscous/diffusion scale in the case of unsteady Stokes eq, i.e. the convective part contribution is very low/trivial?

Comment: And to elaborate more, I had something like this in mind:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis
So, instead of the well known CFL condition of $u\Delta t/ \Delta x \leq C_{max} $ in the case of unsteady Stokes, i.e. diffusion dominates vs the convection, one should use the criteria:

$\nu \Delta t / \Delta x^2\geq C_{min}$

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth please check my edited question for a quote from a paper that states what I am implying!!

Comment: If anything you'll need $\nu \Delta t/\Delta x^2 \le C_\text{min}$ of course. And yes, if you use an explicit time stepping method, that is the condition you have to satisfy. But it is impractical, because it requires such a small time step -- which is why nobody in their right mind uses an explicit time stepping method for the diffusive part.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth so I guess with Implicit Backward Euler my problems should go away, but I think there is some minimum timestep I can safely go to, otherwise local instabilities occur?

Comment: Nope, with implicit methods you are unconditionally stable.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth totally appreciate this, if you could bump it up to an answer I would upvote with pleasure!

Comment: So done! :-) Including a link to more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the time dependent Stokes equation looks like the heat equation:
$$
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \nu\Delta u = f-\nabla p,
$$
plus the incompressibility condition $\nabla \cdot u=0$ that for the current discussion is immaterial. Thus, the same considerations for time step choice apply as for the heat equation.

Consequently, using an *implicit* method such as the backward Euler method generally yields an unconditionally stable method for which you can choose the time step as large as you want. (Although you may want to choose it not too large for accuracy reasons -- stability does not imply accuracy.)

On the other hand, for an *explicit* method, you need to choose the time step $\Delta t$ subject to some CFL-like condition that says that 
$$
  \Delta t \le C \frac{1}{\nu} \Delta x^2
$$
where $\Delta x$ is the mesh size. This is not practical: it requires you to choose the time step *four times smaller for each mesh refinement*. These time steps would be so small that the time discretization error is vastly smaller than the spatial discretization error, and that's not useful. As a consequence, practical implementations do not choose explicit methods for the Stokes equation.

[For an explanation of the *why* this condition arises, see lecture 27 at http://www.math.colostate.edu/~bangerth/videos.html .]